# Doxygen not documenting enum members

Tags: c#, enums, doxygen

I'm trying to document C# code which has some enum definitions with doxygen (ver 1.8.0). For some reason it does document the enum but not the member of the enum.

Here is my code:

```
/// \file Test1.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


///document for namespace
namespace testTheDoxygen
{

        /// <summary>
        /// Document for class
        /// </summary>
        public class Test1
        {

        /// <summary>
        /// Documentation for enum
        /// </summary>
        public enum ThisIsEnum
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Document for member 1
            /// </summary>
            member1,

            /// <summary>
            /// Document for member 2
            /// </summary>
            member2
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I copy and paste your example code and documentation I get, using the default doxygen configuration file, documentation generated for both the enum and the enum members. Can you try with the default configuration file and see if that fixes your problem?

Comment: I would also try making the enumeration not part of the class itself.  It really does not make a great deal of sense.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I did got it working with very simple solution - by updating doxygen. With version 1.8.2 this is working fine.

Comment: Today I had problems with enums using Doxygen 1.9.3. Updating to 1.9.6 solved them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for this was to update doxygen. My sample code is working with version 1.8.2.